# Looping through JSON fails with json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am pulling JSON data from a URL and attempting to display a list of just the display names.

In a way, this would be very easy too loop through if I knew that X amount of results would return each time. However, the results returned will vary from 0 to 50+.

I have done plenty of searches that all say "just use json_decode"... not so much the case.

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "ACK": "SUCCESS",
    "ERROR": null,
    "AGENT": {
        "has_results": 1,
        "agents": [
            {
                "display_name": "Alex",
                "time_in_state": "5214",
                "state": "Aux",
                "callstakentoday": null,
                "callsouttoday": null,
                "agntpriority": null,
                "skill_num": "76"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Bill",
                "time_in_state": "6312",
                "state": "Aux",
                "callstakentoday": null,
                "callsouttoday": null,
                "agntpriority": null,
                "skill_num": "76"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "Carrie",
                "time_in_state": "5982",
                "state": "Aux",
                "callstakentoday": null,
                "callsouttoday": null,
                "agntpriority": null,
                "skill_num": "76"
            },
            {
                "display_name": "David",
                "time_in_state": "4226",
                "state": "Aux",
                "callstakentoday": null,
                "callsouttoday": null,
                "agntpriority": null,
                "skill_num": "76"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SKILL": {
        "has_results": 1,
        "num_skills": 1,
        "skills": [
            {
                "display_name": "Phone Skills",
                "skill_num": "76",
                "callsinqueue": "0",
                "callstoday": "9",
                "abandtoday": "0",
                "lwt": "0",
                "ewt": "0",
                "servicelvl": "100",
                "avgspeedans": "6",
                "talktime": "289"
            }
        ]
    },
    "TIME": 1383766541
}
```

From the examples and documentation I have read, the following code has been created:

```
<?php
    $url="http://myjsonurl.local";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    //echo $json; 

    $json = json_decode($json);
    foreach($json as $item->display_name)
    {
            echo $item->agents->display_name;
    }
?>
```

My end goal is to have a list of only names which I can then display in an alternate webpage.

So my question is... how do I read this page and format the data nicely (perhaps an array I can just print?) so I can utilize it in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following in your code:

```
foreach($json as $item->display_name)
```

This is incorrect and doesn't do what you want. As you can see by doing a `print_r($json)`, the names are in `$json->AGENT->agents`, so you'll want to loop through those items and then traverse the `display_name` using arrow syntax (`$item->display_name`). Once you have the display name, you can push it into an array, and use it however you want.

Your loop should look like below:

```
$names = array(); // initialize empty array
foreach($json->AGENT->agents as $item)
{
    $names[] = $item->display_name;
}

print_r($names); // see the array contents
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alex
    [1] => Bill
    [2] => Carrie
    [3] => David
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/62681)

Note: If you don't know the structure of the JSON object beforehand, then you can use a nested `foreach` loop to retrieve the names.

Comment: Thank you Amal. This is definitely going in the right direction now. Another quick question if I may... I thought it would be cool to color code names based on their state in the JSON. I could change the JSON decode to store the state, but how would I best tie the names and states together to display the data?

Comment: @Fairplay89: That's a different problem (and beyond the scope of this answer, I think). Can you please post that as a new question and explain what you're trying to do in more detail? :)

Comment: Sorry... just brainstorming out loud. Let me do some digging on my own before clobbering up the boards. Thanks!

Comment: @Fairplay89: That's a good idea. Read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/) :)

Answer (score 1):

The array you want to iterate is `$json->AGENT->agents`. Also, your `foreach` syntax is wrong.

Try:

```
foreach($json->AGENT->agents as $item)
{
        echo $item->display_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the JSON data as an array rather then an object, use `json_decode($json, true)` instead. This tells the function to return it as an associative array, as you can read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your **foreach** loop.

```
foreach($json as $item->display_name)
    {
            echo $item->agents->display_name;
    }
```

$item is not an object and you are actually trying in this line to access property "display_name" of none object ($item)

```
foreach($json as $item)
```

Comment: @iambriansreed Pointing to an error like this should often be enough for OP to see what went wrong and how to fix it. Certainly not worth a downvote.

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree, not worth a down vote, which is why I didn't.